# What is the point of [numpy-ndarray]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Is there any rationale behind [numpy-ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy-ndarray)? There is no info for it and I can hardly imagine a [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) question that does not deal with NDArrays to some extent. There are other tags referring to specific aspects of NumPy, [numpy-broadcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy-broadcasting), [numpy-einsum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy-einsum), [numpy-ufunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy-ufunc) and [numpy-memmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy-memmap), but I wouldn't be able to tell what kind of questions should be tagged with [numpy-ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy-ndarray) (and a quick look at some of the tagged questions did not make it clearer). I think it can be replaced with [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) in all cases, or if someone has an actual use for it maybe it could be added to the tag info.

Comment: There are [190 questions tagged numpy-ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy-ndarray), can you please give a rough breakdown of what other tag(s) you think they should use instead?

Comment: @smci: That seems to be covered by "I think it can be replaced with numpy in all cases".

Comment: @user2357112: No, not necessarily. That's why I asked the OP to give specifics, so we can see whether the proposal makes sense or not. I had already looked at those 190 questions and it's unclear; did you?

Comment: @smci Well I was not entirely sure whether the tag should be removed or it had some purpose I could not see. But looking through the questions I do think it can be replaced by `numpy` in all cases. As far as I can see, there are sort of general NumPy questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49306677) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50733987)), questions about using NumPy with other tools (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49990136), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50526033) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51862038)),

Comment: @smci about NumPy and C++ (I think only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51578069)) and finally some about customizing NDArray behavior (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51690755)). Maybe this last one could be legit use, even though I'm not sure if it needs a tag of its own. Can you give some example where you don't see it clear?

Comment: I agree with you; no point in this existing. It should probably be made a synonym of `numpy`.

Comment: Looking at the [Numpy reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/index.html#reference) I would say that the other considerable part of Numpy next to arrays are algorithms. There is for example [LinAlg](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.linalg.html). Arrays are a big part of Numpy but not everything.

Comment: @Trilarion Click though to [the page you just linked to](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.linalg.html), CTRL-F or CMD-F for "array", and observe the description of almost every method on the page light up. That's what jdehesa means when he say he *"can hardly imagine a numpy question that does not deal with NDArrays to some extent"*.

Comment: The main things in numpy that aren't `ndarray`s are the `numpy.matrix` class which are 1. `ndarray` subclasses, and 2. getting more and more deprecated.

Comment: does anyone feel like reviving this? I'm seeing enough [tag:numpy-ndarray] _without_ [tag:numpy] and some even lack [tag:python]. it really ought to be a synonym of [tag:numpy]. I don't understand why anyone would want to "burninate" it though. the tag is useless but not harmful/confusing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As a [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) gold badger and one of the top answerers in the tag, I don't think the [numpy-ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy-ndarray) tag is useful. I can imagine a use for a tag for questions going in-depth in the ndarray representation - stuff like memory layout, memory ownership, endianness, etc., maybe call it [numpy-array-internals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy-array-internals) - but a tag just for questions involving ndarrays isn't much good, and this tag invites usage for any question with arrays in it.

Comment: I disagree with you on the need for any replacement tag. Wouldn't such questions be exceptional, rather than the common? Assuming I'm correct, the tag would get extremely limited usage, and thus provides no real benefit over just a clear question title.

Comment: @jpmc26 I don't think the answer reads as a hard endorsement for [numpy-array-internals], that seems to me rather an example of _what_ might make sense as numpy-*, semantically.

Comment: @AndrasDeak It's not a hard endorsement, but my stance is a hard rejection. =) Thus the author and I are not in agreement.

Comment: @jpmc Questions dealing with Numpy array internals are probably even more rare but is rarity alone sufficient not to have a tag? What is the recommended minimal number in a tag?

Comment: @jpmc26 - if we leave aside the author's imagination about other related tags which might be created, do you agree with the rest of their statement. **"As a `numpy` gold badger and one of the top answerers in the tag, @user2357112 [doesn't] think the `numpy-ndarray` tag is useful. [..snip...] a tag just for questions involving ndarrays isn't much good, and this tag invites usage for any question with arrays in it."**

Comment: @jpmc26: Why should we care about your disagreement with this answer, given that the said tag does not in fact exist (and no one is proposing creating it)?  I don't mean to be rude, but there seems to be a lot more heat than light in these comments right now.

Comment: @Kevin You don't have to care, but the mention *is* a proposal, even if it's one the author isn't sure about. So I expressed an opinion that it shouldn't be created. Do with that what you will.